# Unique index not working on Mongoose schema

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, schema

I have a schema setup like this:

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
  id: {type: String, required: true, unique: true, index: true, default: mongoose.Types.ObjectId},

  name: { type: String, required: true },
  email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true, index: true },
  mobile: { type: String, unique: true, sparse: true },
  password: { type: String, required: true }

});
```

Seems to work great except the email field is letting in duplicates, despite have `unique:true` set. I do the following:

```
User.create({
  name: req.body.name,
  email: req.body.email,
  mobile: req.body.mobile,
  password: password
}, function(err, user) {
  if (err) return res.send({ invalid : true });
});
```

If `req.body.email` is a value that's already in the database, the query above should return `err`. But it doesn't, it creates the new user perfectly fine, resulting in duplicate emails in the database.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Try this: email: { type: String, required: true, index: { unique: true } }

Comment: @RaxWunter unfortunately didn't work. It seems that the entire database is ignoring unique fields.

Comment: Add `User.on('index', function(err) { console.log(err); });` to see if there's an error preventing the index from being created. Also, if a non-unique index was previously present on `email` you'll need to manually drop it so it can be recreated as unique.

Answer (score 0):

mongo and hence mongoose will assign an automatic id fields to your document. usually that is "_id". 
Try removing the "id" from your schema to fix your issue.